# attached function to .hide() event gets triggered when children are hidden, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, hide, decorator

I modified the jQuery .hide() function like this:

```
/*
 *This chunk will help us attach other functions to the hide events
 */
var _old = $.fn.hide;
$.fn.hide = function(){
    var self = this;
    _old.apply(this,arguments).promise().done(function(){
        self.trigger("hide");
    });
    return this;
};
```

I did this so I don't have to use `.trigger('hide')` when I attach methods to the hide event.  I have run into a small problem with this: It looks like the methods will get triggered every time a child element is hidden if you attach a method to the `.hide()` function of the parent element.  Please see this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/286/.

I would like the alert to only show when we hide the main div, which can be done by clicking the "hide main div" button.  But, as you can see, the alert is shown when you switch tabs that are inside the main div.

Does anyone know how I can keep the attached methods (the alert pop up) to only fire when the specified selector in hidden (`$('#main_div')`), and not any other elements?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:

I made a little filter to the `.on('hide'..` function that makes sure the ID that triggered the `hide()` is the one we want.  Still not the exact solution i was looking for (ie. making the wrapper script do it), but is getting closer: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/296/

Comment: So you want te alert to pop only when the button is pressed? why don't you attack the alert to the button click instead?

Comment: The button is just used to initiate the `.hide()` for this example.  In an application the the `.hide()` can come from different actions.  The alert is just to let us know the attached method has fired.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for? i avoid the event propagation when the "tabMe" hide event is triggered, but allow it when the big div is hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/294/

Comment: That is pretty good, but then you would have to put extra lines for every child element that could be hidden.  Could be a lot of code if you have a lot of dynamic elements inside the main_div.  I was messing with the fiddle, and I came up with a similar filter, but just in one place where you attach the methods to the hide event, here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/295/. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think using .children() with event propagation would have worked fine as well. Just thinking :)